# Error running BLAST when database is on external hard drive

Tags: storage, blast

I have two Macs: a Desktop with a 3 TB hard drive, and a laptop with a 512 GB SSD and an attached 8 TB USB-C external hard drive. I have the same BLAST database set up on both; for the laptop, the database is on the external hard drive. When I run a BLAST query on the desktop, it runs fine. However, when I run the exact same command on the laptop, I get the following error message.

Error memory mapping:/Volumes/LaCie/data/blastdb/all_proteins.FASTA.03.phr openedFilesCount=251 threadID=0
BLAST Database error: Cannot memory map /Volumes/LaCie/data/blastdb/all_proteins.FASTA.03.phr. Number of files opened: 251

I had no luck Googling this message, which is why I'm asking for help here! Is this error related to the BLAST database being on the external hard drive? Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm running into the same issue, but monitoring my memory usage while my blast runs shows I'm not even reaching 40% of my memory available memory